# Why does the "C++ Core Guidelines" recommends the prefer independent functions instead of class members?

Tags: c++, class-method

The [C++ Core Guidelines section C.4](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#c4-make-a-function-a-member-only-if-it-needs-direct-access-to-the-representation-of-a-class) recommends "make a function a member only if it needs direct access to the representation of a class", using the following example:

```
class Date {
    // ... relatively small interface ...
};

// helper functions:
Date next_weekday(Date);
bool operator==(Date, Date);
```

I don't understand the reasoning here. In my opinion this would be a better option:

```
class Date {
    // ... relatively small interface ...

    Date next_weekday(Date const&) const;
    bool operator==(Date const&) const;
};
```

What is the advantage in this reasoning?

Comment: *Why* do you think member functions would be a better option? :)

Comment: I'm with you on this, subject to making the "helper functions" `static`.

Comment: Look at [how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsulation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1692084/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsulation)

Comment: Your'e aware of the C++ code philosophy of "don't pay for what you don't use", I hope. It can be said that breaking encapsulation incurs a price. So this guideline just applies the same philosophy to the price of breaking encapsulation.

Comment: Even though this is a dup, I disagree with the downvoting. Going from Core Guidelines to something written by Scott Meyer is non-trivial. Also, the other question knows this is about encapsulation. Finally, the CG specifies independent and the other post is about non-member. In short, finding the dup is non-trivial for most people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Member functions* have access to `private` members of a class. This means that they can use the internal representation of the class in their logic.

*Non-member functions* only have access to `public` members of a class. This means that they can only use the publicly exposed interface of the class, thus improving encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

### It increases encapsulation

When you change the private implementation of Date, you only have to check `// ... relatively small interface ...` for places where previous assumptions may no longer hold, instead of `// ... relatively small interface ...` + `next_weekday` + `operator==` + ...